# Deleting PFUser objects from database in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I just started working with servers in swift and I'm using parse server to store a database of users when they create an account for my app. I have this function called sign up that is linked to a sign up button which works fine and properly stores user's info into my parse database.:

```
@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: AnyObject) {

   //I first check to see if the users left any of the fields blank

    if firstName.text == "" || lastName.text == "" || email.text == "" || userName.text == "" || password.text == "" {

        createAlert(title: "Error in form", message: "Please fill in all text fields")


    //If everything is filled in
    }else{


        let user = PFUser()
        user.username = userName.text
        user["firstname"] = firstName.text
        user["lastname"] = lastName.text
        user.email = email.text
        user.password = password.text


        user.signUpInBackground(block: { (success, error) in                
            if error != nil {

                var displayErrorMessage = "Please try again later."

                if let errorMessage = (error! as NSError).userInfo["error"] as? String {

                    displayErrorMessage = errorMessage
                }

                self.createAlert(title: "Signup error", message: displayErrorMessage)

            }else{
                print("User signed up")
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me write a function that deletes a specified user or many loops through all users and deletes them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't put that code on a client. Yuck.

Deleting a user is something you want to safeguard very carefully. Put that in cloud code if you really need it, and do validation to ensure it's used properly.

I.e., a user should only be able to make the request to delete their own user.  Make a cloud code function that has the parameter `userId`, and check that param against `request.user.id`.  If they don't match, return an error. Otherwise you can call the destroy method on that User.

You should also put a CLP in place to only allow the master key to delete a User object.

Comment: How to do I put that in cloud code?..Can you possibly show me please?