# swift 3 store code on the cloud

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, cloud

I just started working with servers in swift and I'm using parse server hosted by AWS to store a database of users when they create an account for my app. I have this function called sign up that is linked to a sign up button which works fine and properly stores user's info into my parse database.:

```
@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: AnyObject) {

//I first check to see if the users left any of the fields blank

if firstName.text == "" || lastName.text == "" || email.text == "" || userName.text == "" || password.text == "" {

    createAlert(title: "Error in form", message: "Please fill in all text fields")


//If everything is filled in
}else{


    let user = PFUser()
    user.username = userName.text
    user["firstname"] = firstName.text
    user["lastname"] = lastName.text
    user.email = email.text
    user.password = password.text


    user.signUpInBackground(block: { (success, error) in                
        if error != nil {

            var displayErrorMessage = "Please try again later."

            if let errorMessage = (error! as NSError).userInfo["error"] as? String {

                displayErrorMessage = errorMessage
            }

            self.createAlert(title: "Signup error", message: displayErrorMessage)

        }else{
            print("User signed up")
        }
    })
}

}
```

Now i need help storing this code on the cloud.

The reason why I ask this is because I had previously posted a question a little different on stack overflow: [Deleting PFUser objects from database in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886751/deleting-pfuser-objects-from-database-in-swift/44890968#44890968)

And in the response, I was told to store this exact function in cloud code (rather than locally) and I don't know how to do that. 
Can anyone show me how it's done?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What do you mean “store this code in the cloud”? You should edit your question to include more details about exactly what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @joshua Nozzi I edited it

Comment: I don't think `Singup` and `Login` with Parse should be on cloud, if you are just registering user or trying to login. Use the code provided by `Parse SDK` on client. But if you are trying to do some other heavy stuffs you should probably consider using cloud functions

Comment: I'm asking for an example...Like would would I cpnvert this signup Function into a cloud function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they told you is to implement that code in the server, the server should be the one to process the function you ask for in the past question, this one, I think you have already done it because you said the info is stored successfully, but what the answer above this says is that to implement that code in an actual app you should investigate more about security and encryption to protect users information.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming what it means when you want to "store your code in the cloud" is that all personal info (name, email, password) should be handled from the backend, not that you actually store the code in the cloud. You should handle sensitive personal data from the server-side and not the client-side. This involves server-side encryption and handling requests with SSL exchanges. This is beyond the scope of my expertise and this question, and I highly encourage that you do more research before you try to tackle this problem in your app. Here are some links I found:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html

https://www.raywenderlich.com/92667/securing-ios-data-keychain-touch-id-1password